# C# Task seems to block without being awaited

Tags: c#, mysql, task

I have this method, which executes an sql command on a mysql database on multiple connections.

```
public async Task<long[][]> ExecuteCommand(string sqlCommand, int tries, int concurrent,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        EnsureConnections(concurrent);

        //This line takes about 2 seconds before hitting the log method when using mysql, postgres and sqlserver execute this line instantly and block at Task.WhenAll
        var tasks = Connections
            .Select(connection => connection.ExecuteQuery(sqlCommand, tries, cancellationToken))
            .ToList();
        Log.Debug("Completed gathering tasks");

        return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

this is connection.executeQuery:

```
public override async Task<long[]> ExecuteQuery(string sqlCommand, int tries,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IsExecuting = true;

        var times = await FunctionTimer.GetOperationTimesAsync(async () =>
        {
            using (var command =
                new MySqlCommand(sqlCommand, BaseConnection as MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
        }, tries, cancellationToken);

        IsExecuting = false;
        return times;
    }
```

As you can see the ExecuteQuery method is async, and ExecuteNonQueryAsync is also async.
The weird thing is I also have this set up for Postgres and SQL Server, which both block when they're supposed to (at Task.WhenAll(tasks)). Why does the mysql version block when I'm only putting the tasks in a list?